# How can I get the last word after a special character?

Tags: javascript, regex

So far I have the following:

```
 \- (.*)
```

And from the following text:

```
September 2014 - Media
```

I need to get "Media", tho I am getting "- Media"

Comment: Better also tag it with "Javascript" if looking for a JS regex as there's a lot difference among specific regex flavors.

Comment: True, I am just new at this and I didn't know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is correct just print the group index 1 instead of group 0 and you don't need to escape `-` symbol.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pM9pD0/3)

See the captured string `Media` at the right side in the above demo link.

**OR**

Use the below regex to match only `Media`,

```
- \K.*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pM9pD0/2)

You could use a lookbehind if your language fail to support `\K`,

```
(?<=- ).*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pM9pD0/4)

```
> "September 2014 - Media".match(/[^- ]+$/g)
[ 'Media' ]
> var r = "September 2014 - Media";
undefined
> console.log(/- (.*)/.exec(r)[1])
Media
```

Comment: @Monica which language are you running? http://www.regexr.com/ designed only to support javascript. `\K`, lookbehinds won't be supported in js.

Comment: Javascript. I think this language doesn't support it

Comment: @Monica added for js also.

Answer (score 2):

If your language allows lookbehind, try :

```
  (?<=-)(.*)
```

if doesn't simply use :

```
  ([^-]*)$
```

Comment: I am using Javascript

Comment: Then u can use the alternative solution. And also add `javascript` tag to the question.